# surface area of the surface $z=x^2+y^2$ over the circle.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find the surface area of the surface $z=x^2+y^2$ that lies above the circle $x^2+y^2\leq 16$

What I tried

If $z=f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ then $f'_{x}=2x$ and $f'_{y}=2y$.

The surface over the region defined $$\iint_{\text{R}}\sqrt{(f'_{x})^2+(f'_{y})^2+1}dxdy=\iint_{\text{R}}\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+1}dxdy.$$

Now convert it into polar coordinates

$x^2+y^2=r^2$ and $dxdy=rdrd\phi$

But I did not understand How can I set up limit Here.

Could some help me to solve it. Thanks

Comment: $r^2\le16$, no ?

Comment: Means i set $0\leq r\leq4$ and How do i set $\phi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, in polar coordinates, $r= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le4$ and the surface integral is

$$\int\int_{\text{R}}\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+1}dxdy
= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{4}\sqrt{4r^2+1}rdr d\phi
=\frac\pi6 (65\sqrt{65}-1)
$$

Answer (score 1):

The surface is a porabaloid, so $\phi \in [0,2\pi)$.  Your integral should be

$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^4 r\sqrt{1+4r^2} drd\phi.
$$