# Find the surface area of the portion inside the cylindrical surface $x^2 +y^2 =1$, where the surface is given by $z = x^2 + y^2$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the surface area of the portion inside the cylindrical $x^{2} +y^{2} =1$, where the surface is given by $z\ =\ x^{2} \ +\ y^{2}$

Here is my thinking:
\begin{array}{l}
\iint _{S}\sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial Z}{\partial x}\right)^{2} +\left(\frac{\partial Z}{\partial y}\right)^{2} +1} \ dxdy\\
=\iint _{S}\sqrt{4x^{2} +4y^{2} +1} \ dxdy\ \ \ ( x=rcos\theta ,\ y=rsin\theta )\\
=\int _{0}^{2\pi }\int _{0}^{1} r\sqrt{4r^{2} +1} \ drd\theta \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \left( Let\ 1+4r^{2} =u,\ du=8rdr\right)\\
=\int _{0}^{2\pi } d\theta \frac{1}{8}\int _{1}^{5}\sqrt{u} du\\
=2\pi \cdot \frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{2}{3} \cdot 5^{\frac{3}{2}} -\frac{2}{3}\right)\\
=2\pi \left(\frac{1}{12} \cdot 5^{\frac{3}{2}} -\frac{1}{12}\right)\\
=\frac{5^{\frac{3}{2}} -1}{6} \pi 
\end{array}

Is it right? The result seems incorrect (Sorry, I don't have the correct answer). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is correct, see also this very similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3640292/surface-area-of-the-surface-z-x2y2-over-the-circle?noredirect=1

Comment: @RobertZ Thanks for your response.